# Folder accessible to non admin but not dynamic report

Tags: custom-report-type, dynamic

I created dynamic report in an folder and linked in custom button. Non admins were given viewer permission for the folder. However, it is not accessible via custom button. Am I missing something here? It is new custom report type and new custom object
Thanks
Athimathi

Comment: Are you getting an error?  Can admins view the report from the custom button?  Have you give permissions to the custom object to non-admins?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. It turned out Custom report type was in development rather deployed.